How do I efficiently compute the fidelity between two stabilizer tableau states?
I have two stabilizer tableaus $T_1$ and $T_2$. How do I efficiently compute the fidelity of their stabilizer states?

You can take advantage of the fact that tableaus are both a state, and invertible Clifford operations that prepare their state starting from the $|0\rangle$ state. Let $|\psi_1\rangle$ be the state of tableau $T_1$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ be the state of tableau $T_2$. The fidelity between the two states is the same as the fidelity between $|0\rangle$ and $T_2^{-1} T_1 |0\rangle$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\langle \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle
&= F(|\psi_1\rangle, |\psi_2\rangle)
\\&= F(T_2^{-1}|\psi_1\rangle, T_2^{-1}|\psi_2\rangle)
\\&= F(T_2^{-1}|\psi_1\rangle, |0\rangle)
\\&= F(T_2^{-1} T_1 |0\rangle, |0\rangle)
\\&= \langle 0 | T_2^{-1} T_1 |0\rangle
\end{aligned}$$
To compute the fidelity between a state and $|0\rangle$, you can use any stabilizer simulator that reveals whether a measurement was random or determined. What you do is postselect onto getting a $|0\rangle$ measurement for every qubit, while tracking the overall probability $p$ of this succeeding. This will take $O(n^3)$ time where $n$ is the number of qubits.
Example implementation using stim:
import stim


def tableau_fidelity(t1: stim.Tableau, t2: stim.Tableau) -> float:
    t3 = t2**-1 * t1
    sim = stim.TableauSimulator()
    sim.set_inverse_tableau(t3)

    p = 1
    for q in range(len(t3)):
        e = sim.peek_z(q)
        if e == -1:
            return 0
        if e == 0:
            p *= 0.5
            sim.postselect_z(q, desired_value=False)

    return p

Testing it:
from typing import Iterable
import numpy as np


def assert_correct_tableau_fidelity(u: Iterable[complex], v: Iterable[complex]):
    expected = abs(np.dot(u, np.conj(v)))**2
    ut = stim.Tableau.from_state_vector(u, endian='little')
    vt = stim.Tableau.from_state_vector(v, endian='little')
    actual = tableau_fidelity(ut, vt)
    np.testing.assert_allclose(actual, expected, rtol=1e-5)


def test_tableau_fidelity():
    s = 0.5**0.5
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([1, 0], [0, 1])
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([1, 0], [1, 0])
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([0, 1], [1, 0])
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([s, s], [s, s])
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([s, s], [s, -s])
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([s, -s], [s, s])
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([s, 1j * s], [s, s])
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([s, s], [s, s])
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([1, 0], [s, s])
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([0, 1], [s, s])
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, s, s])
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, s, s])
    assert_correct_tableau_fidelity([0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1j * s, s])
    for n in range(6):
        for _ in range(10):
            assert_correct_tableau_fidelity(
                stim.Tableau.random(n).to_state_vector(),
                stim.Tableau.random(n).to_state_vector(),
            )


Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be the binary representation of the two stabilizer groups (i.e. up to phases). Then, the fidelity between the corresponding stabilizer states $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ is
$$
|\langle \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle|^2 = \begin{cases} 2^{-n} |S_1\cap S_2| & \text{if phases agree on } S_1\cap S_2\,, \\ 0 & \text{else}. \end{cases}
$$
Hence, another way of computing the overlap is to construct a basis of $S_1\cap S_2$, e.g. via the Zassenhaus algorithm (essentially Gaussian elimination) and check whether the phases agree on this basis. However, the runtime is, of course, still $O(n^3)$.

Aaronson, Gottesman "Improved simulation of stabilizer circuits"
Kueng, Gross "Qubit stabilizer states are complex projective 3-designs"

Note: The overlap $\langle \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle$ depends on the phase convention for stabilizer states.
